# Generate a comma separated list from Session Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

I have a session array [cart] of which contains user id numbers.  I am trying to generate a list of email addresses from the contact table WHERE the contact id numbers in the session = the contact_id in the database.

Here is my code.

```
// Find cart members from the session array
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$val) {
    $contactid = $val;

    // Query the database for cart members
    $cartresult = mysql_query("SELECT contact.email FROM contact WHERE contact.contact_id = '$contactid'");
    $emailresult = mysql_query($emailquery) or DIE (mysql_error());
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($emailresult)) { 
        $emailAry[] = $r['email']; 
    }
}

// Create comma separated list from email array
if (count($emailAry)) {
    $list = implode(", ", $emailAry);

    $list = str_replace(" ,", "", $list);
```

Apparently there is no value for $emailAry because the if statement is being neglected.

Any idea why this would be?

Comment: What does `print_r($_SESSION['cart'])` output?

Comment: The array is in the session correctly.  Zlatan figured out what the problem was.  Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$emailquery` from my perspective is undefined.

```
    $emailAry = array();

    // Find cart members from the session array
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$val) {
        $cartresult = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM contact WHERE contact_id = '$val'");
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($cartresult)) { 
            $emailAry[] = $r['email']; 
        }
    }

    // Create comma separated list from email array
    if (count($emailAry)) {
        $list = implode(",", $emailAry);

        // no need to replace ', ' with '', implode will do all the job creating a CSV :)
        //$list = str_replace(" ,", "", $list);
    }
```

Comment: please check my answer as accepted if this was a solution for you :) click on the gray arrow-like shape underneeth my awswer count :)

Comment: I did it.  I also went back through my previous questions and accepted other answers now that I know how... now I have enough reputation to upvote your answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `$emailAry` array in the outer scope, so you can access it from the code out of the while and foreach, like his:

```
$emailAry = array();
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$val) {
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this it's easy and fast

```
 $to = '';
 foreach ($result->result() as $row){
    $to .=  $row->id.',';            
 }

 $to = rtrim($to,',');
```

Change it according to yours.